# Audio Redirection Over RDP

Tags: c++, driver

How we can redirect audio port  over RDP Programatically...

Explanation: When we set the option from Remote Desktop Connection -> Local Resources ->play in this system , then we get the Remote Audio at Terminal server ...How internally that happens ...

Comment: You want to programatically create an RDP connection with the local audio redirection set up? Just save an RDP file with that setting set...

Comment: Thanks Ben...My requirement is to bring the sound to terminal client machine when the user selects play in remote system(whatever playing in remote machine)...So exactly how the microsoft has implemented play in local machine.

Comment: Are you using the RDP ActiveX control? Are you using MSTSC.EXE? Or are you re-implementing an RDP client from scratch?

Comment: I am tracking mstsc and have written a client plugin dll to invoke the static channel communication...Is there any method to redirect the sound from remote side to local machine audio driver...Best thing is how to bring the remote audio at the time when the user select play in remote machine...

Comment: Hi Ben, My main purpose is to redirect audio from a terminal server to a terminal client when a user select play in remote machine...so main goal is to redirect the sound ...Microsoft has implemented this for play in Local machine that is what i exactly need the same implementation for the option play in remote machine...

Comment: Yaa I am using  mstsc.exe...Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "tracking mstsc"? If you are using MSTSC.exe all you have to do is check the box saying "Play on this computer" in the sound settings. If that is not what you want, what DO you want?

Comment: Play on this computer that option I need to implement programatically  Ben...I am using mstsc to remotely access the server but my requirement is when one user select play in remote computer that should be played in local machine which is nothing but play on this computer...so any guideline for implementing that play on this compter ...Thanks Ben once again...

Comment: Tracking means if I register a client Addin.dll at client side in computer/HKEY_CURRENT_USER/Software/Microsoft/Terminal Server/Default/Addin.dll then at the time of inoking mstsc.exe I can able to track each and every happening inside the mstsc simple passing messages...then create a static virtual channel and through which I send audio data from server side...That is the one way of implementation but it has drawbacks...

Comment: MSTSC already does this. Just use the existing feature.

Answer (score 0):

You can start MSTSC.EXE with any combination of desired options by creating an RDP configuration file, which is a simple text file, and using that from the command line. You can create the file either in a temp directory for one-off use or it can be saved in the user's profile.

```
mstsc.exe [connection_file.RDP]
```

The easiest way to learn about the connection file options, is to run MSTSC.EXE and use the "Options" button to show advanced options. Then set the options you want, and save the RDP file. You can then open the RDP file in notepad for it is a simple text file, and the options will be visible.

For a  list of RDP connection file options, and an example file, see here:

- http://coe.uncc.edu/mosaic/remote_desk/RDP%20File%20Settings.htm

This is the setting to bring sound to the client computer.

```
audiomode:i:0
```

This setting must also be enabled for the server. If it is disabled at the server audio will not be played whatever setting you use.

For more MSTSC.EXE command line options see here:

- http://windows.microsoft.com/en-GB/windows-vista/Use-command-line-parameters-with-Remote-Desktop-Connection

Comment: Thanks a lot Ben.Have a great time with you ahead...I will try that one what you suggest...